# Duplicate Value when parameter names are different and constructor chaining only giving zeros as output

Tags: java, constructor

Im trying to make 3 constructors to put into someone elses code. Im getting 2 weird errors. 1. its giving me a duplicate error when the names are different and 2. Its outputting only zeros even when there is user input to say other wise. Im assuming its my constructors but Im not sure. EDIT: Ive added the rest of the code for reference

[image]

```
public class MyDateChoice {
   private static final String[] monthNames = {"January", "February", 
      "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", 
      "September", "October", "November", "December"};
   private static final int[] monthDays = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 
      31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

   private int day; // day of the month
   private int month; // month in the year
   private int year; // year

   public MyDateChoice () {
       this (0,0,0);
       }

   public MyDateChoice (int month, int day, int year) {
    }

   public MyDateChoice (String monthName, int day, int year) {
   }


   public MyDateChoice(int ddd, int year) {
      if (year < 0) { // validate year
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("year must be > 0");
      }

      if (ddd < 1 || ddd > 366) { // check for invalid day
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("day out of range");
      }

      this.year = year;

      int dayTotal = 0;

      for (int m = 1; 
         m < 13 && (dayTotal + daysInMonth(m, year)) < ddd; ++m) {
         dayTotal += daysInMonth(m, year);
         this.month = 1;
      } 

      this.day = ddd - dayTotal;
   }

   // Set the day
   public void setDay(int day) {
      if (day < 1 || day > daysInMonth(month, year)) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("day out of range for current month");
      }

      this.day = day;
   }

   // Set the month
   public void setMonth(int month) {
      if (month <= 0 || month > 12) { // validate month
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("month must be 1-12");
      }

      this.month = month;
   }

   // Set the year
   public void setYear(int year) {
      if (year < 0) { // validate year
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("year must be > 0");
      }

      this.year = year;
   }

   // return Date in format: mm/dd/yyyy
   public String toString() {
      return String.format("%d/%d/%d", month, day, year); 
   }

   // return Date in format: MonthName dd, yyyy
   public String toMonthNameDateString() {
      return String.format(
         "%s %d, %d", monthNames[month ], day, year);
   }

   // return Date in format DDD YYYY
   public String toDayDateString() {
      return String.format("%d %d", convertToDayOfYear(), year);
   }

   // Return the number of days in the month
   private static int daysInMonth(int month, int year) {
      return leapYear(year) && month == 2 ? 29 : monthDays[month - 1];
   }

   // test for a leap year
   private static boolean leapYear(int year) {
      if (year % 400 == 0 || (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0)) {
         return true;
      }
      else {
         return false;
      }
   }

   // convert mm and dd to ddd
   private int convertToDayOfYear() {
      int ddd = 0;

      for (int m = 1; m < month; ++m) {
         if (leapYear(year) && m == 2) {
            ddd += 29;
         }
         else  {
            ddd += monthDays[m -1];
         }
      } 

      ddd += day;
      return ddd;
   }

   // convert from month name to month number
   private static int convertFromMonthName(String monthName) {
      for (int subscript = 0; subscript < 12; subscript++) {
         if (monthName.equals(monthNames[subscript])) {
            return subscript + 1;
         }
      }

      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid month name");
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code that calls the constructors to know why the second issue is happening?

Comment: "its giving me a duplicate error when the names are different" - which constructor would you expect `new MyDateChoice(10, 2020)` to use? Overloading needs the parameter *types* to be different. So it's not really a weird error - it's just the way Java works. As for output... code that doesn't compile can't output anything, so we don't know what you're running. Additionally, please show code as *text* in future - potentially along with a screenshot, but *always* include the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first issue, The constructor does not really care about the name of the variables as they are aliases. It only cares about the type of the input parameters, in this case both methods have two int inputs.

For the second issue, it seems for now you have implemented the default constructor which simply initializes all your members to zero. That's the reason why you are getting everything as zero (I am guessing this is the one only used for initialization of your new objects for now)

Design tips:

- Rather than having setter for every member, it is a good practice to follow the builder pattern (https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-the-builder-pattern)
- Rather than having many constructors with different parameter types you can use generic methods (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) or even simpler way is to use conversions. To elaborate this further:

This is what you have:

```
public MyDateChoice (int month, int day, int year) {
}
public MyDateChoice (String monthName, int day, int year) {
}
```

What you can do is create a static method that converts the month name from string to int, and this allows you to eliminate the second constructor:

```
public MyDateChoice (int month, int day, int year) {
}
public static int getMonthNameInt(Stringt monthName) {
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Another question are my constructors right? They seem right but then the output is constantly zero...At this point Im assuming its a bug in the rest of the code but I just want to make sure